# Find out what filesystem a file or directory is part of

Tags: filesystem

I have a lot of filesystems:

- `/` on a PCI-E SSD
- `swap` on a SATA SSD
- `/media/ned` is a RAID5 array
- `/tmp` lives on RAM
- Parts of `/home/oli` are symlinked and bind-mounted in from `ned`
- I also have `/media/jeff/` which is RAID1 that I store backups and bind-mount `~/.wine` in off.

It's actually a lot more complicated than that. There are all sorts of extra symlinks that I need to untangle in the long run but for now I just need a nice way of taking a path and finding out where it physically lives.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not probably the best or the correct answer, but df can do it:

```
javier@todocolor:~$ df /boot/grub/
S.ficheros         Bloques de 1K   Usado    Dispon Uso% Montado en
/dev/sda2               918354    184202    685154  22% /boot
javier@todocolor:~$ df .
S.ficheros         Bloques de 1K   Usado    Dispon Uso% Montado en
/dev/md0              75532064  13930424  57795044  20% /
```

Take the first and the last column.

Comment: For eg long NFS mount paths, df sometimes splits its report across more than one line, so it might be wise to take the second line rather than the last one, or to use --portability (a switch whose portability I doubt!).

Answer (score 11):

```
df /path/to/filename    # to find out what device a file or folder is on
```

Comment: followed by `mount` to see the filesystem for each mounted location